# How can I make a file with alias's on it, put it on usb stick, and make the alias's accesible when I insert the usb drive

Tags: command-line, usb, alias

Hi Im very new to ubuntu and linux, I know how to create the file and put alias's on it, I was wondering how do I make this file accesible only when I insert the usb drive,meaning the alias's would work only when the usb drive is connected, should I Add the usb drive path to bashrc? Im very confused, any help would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you are asking, so I will assume a few things.
Assuming the following:

1. The mount point for the usb drive is `/mnt/usbdrive`.
2. The location of your target file is `/mnt/usbdrive/myfile`.
3. By alias you mean a soft link. Something you create with `ln -s /mnt/usbdrive/myfile ~/myfile`.

Then, `ls -al ~` will list an entry like

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user     user      33 jun 29  2020 myfile -> /mnt/usbdrive/myfile
```

This soft link will automatically work only when the usb drive is connected.
Otherwise, the soft link will show up as a broken link.

If your file is an executable file, and instead of item 3 above you use `alias myfile=/mnt/usbdrive/myfile`, then, again, executing `myfile` will work (there is no need to add anything to `~/.bashrc`) only when the usb drive is connected.
Otherwise you will get an error message.

If you, in addition, add `/mnt/usbdrive` to your `PATH` in `~/.bashrc`, you don't need the alias to be able to execute `myfile` regardless of your current directory.
But, still, it will automatically work only when the usb drive is connected.
Otherwise you will get an error message.

Comment: Very good answer. Indeed, these are three different ways to Rome, so take your pick. Creating a softlink in your `~/bin` or `~/.local/bin` directory is according to me the easiest approach. Also  an `alias` is a good option. I would not proceed to changing the `PATH`, however. 1) you do not want to alter your environment for every new program around the corner 2) that path is searched, byt while the USB is not mounted, it is invalid.

Comment: @vanadium - Agreed!

Comment: @vanadium - Something for Meta... New contributors are extremely prone to not giving feedback...